# Not able to install ipa file of my ipad app in iOS 10 beta 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, ipa, ios10

I am able to install my application till iOS 9 but it is not getting installed in iOS 10 beta 3.
Even I tried to download application from app store then also not able to install.

Kindly help to resolve the issue.

Thanks

Comment: which iPhone you are using?

Comment: I am using iPad Air with iOS10  beta version.